# É possível desenvolver multiplataforma mobile usando Java?

Tags: java, mobile, cross-platform

Estou migrando o desenvolvimento dos meus aplicativos para Java para construir aplicativos nativos para Android. Gostaria de expandir meus aplicativos para outras plataformas, como iOS e Windows Phone. É possível fazer isto com **Java**?

Comment: Eu sugiro desenvolver utilizando plataformas híbridas, como o Cordova. Você pode usar HTML5, CSS3 e JS para desenvolver suas aplicações e compilá-las para as 3 plataformas. Se não se importar em adotar AngularJS então, você pode utilizar o Ionic Framework.

Comment: Já pensei e utilizar o Cordova e Webstorm, mas gostaria de manter a linguagem nativa no Android. Teria algum outro aplicativo de desenvolvimento multiplataform que fizesse o mesmo com Java?

Comment: Ué o java não era multiplataforma de pc, a geladeiras? :P

Comment: Existe esse projeto para portar o openJDK no iOS, Android e Windows Phone  
http://openjdk.java.net/projects/mobile/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Procure aqui: http://mobile-frameworks-comparison-chart.com/

No momento que procurei, encontrei três frameworks:

- eMobc
- Kendo UI
- Mono for Android

Porém isso não é garantia que a linguagem nativa seja mantida no Android (será nativo, mas você não codificará diretamente com a API do Android e sim com classes fornecidas pelo framework, que poderão inclusive ser convertidas para um formato intermediário).

Procurando por coisas como "cross platform java" encontrei também essas opções:

https://www.codenameone.com/

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/maf/overview/index.html

https://robovm.com/

http://juniversal.org/

Comment: O site de busca parece muito bom, mas ambos parecem não conter nada sobre Java. :(

Comment: Incluí outras opções que encontrei no Google.

Comment: Muito bom, de todas as pesquisas encontrei apenas aplicativos pagos. Obrigado pelo tempo e pelos exemplos, atendeu as minhas expectativas! :)

Answer (score 1):

Tem o [Tabris]

http://www.infoq.com/br/news/2013/09/tabris-mobile-multiplataforma

Porém o Tabris é voltado para empresa e tem a licença paga: "O Tabris não é um framework de código aberto, mas as licenças corporativas dão acesso aos fontes."

Link: http://developer.eclipsesource.com/tabris/

Answer (score 0):

Honestamente, não acredito que você consiga aproveitar o código nativo Java para, digamos compilar direto para iOS ou Windows Phone. De alguma forma você vai sempre ter que adaptar seu código para atender alguma funcionalidade específica do sistema.

O que você consegue é usar frameworks, que geralmente vão ser plataformas híbridas que usam html e js, como o pessoal já mencionou. Essa é a forma mais rápida, e basicamente o aplicativo roda como se fosse uma pagina web na plataforma (na maioria deles), só que o usuário abre o app no lugar de acessar um endereço.

Outra solução seria usar uma linguagem que consiga 'buildar' para outras plataformas mobile. como [GO](http://www.sitepoint.com/ios-and-android-programming-with-go/), mas como mencionado no artigo pode não valer a pena, por que sempre vai ter um impacto de alguma forma (e não é java), interface não nativa, ou código não nativo do android, por exemplo. Acho que C# vai pelo mesmo caminho.